# how to use charts a problem with chart spring boot?

Tags: javascript, spring, charts, highcharts

I have this file which contains the js of the line chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        width: 500
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Line chart'
    },
    xAxix: {
        categories: ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30]
    }]
});
```

this is the request mapping

```
// RH home
@RequestMapping("/rh")
public ModelAndView rhHome(Principal principal) {
    // ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    user rhUser = RhRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());

    mv.addObject("rh", rhUser);
    mv.setViewName("rh");
    return mv;
}
```

my jsp page

```
</div>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/rh.js"></script>
</div>
```

The problem is it doesn't show anything in the page.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: could be a typo... `xAxis` instead of  `xAxix`

Comment: how can i add xAxis instead

Comment: There is a small issue in your Highcharts config - there should be `xAxis`, but even with that chart should be rendered, so the problem will be with your attempting to show the chart in the spring environment. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3sdkrhpw/ Unfortunately, I don't know the spring boot and I am not able to help you. I am not sure if there is any spring boot Highcharts wrapper. List of API wrappers created by community you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/wrappers-addons-and-plugins/wrappers/